# ggplot with three y-variables R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a plot that look like below. Currently, I have a data with 4 headers (Type, Value1, Value2 and the total value). What I try to achieve is that I want to categorise the Type column with output Value1, Value2 and the total value at the same time.

I have a code below, but it seems doesn't work! Please anyone able to point me into the correct direction.

```
    df <- data.frame(Type = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h","i"),
      Value1 = c(1, 32, 63, 94, 125, 156,187,218,249),
      Value2 = c(125, 5, 125, 76, 3, 125,3,2,100),
Total = c(126,37,188,170,128,281,190,220,349))

plot <- ggplot(df,aes(x = Type,y=c("Value1","Value2","Total"),fill = EVTYPE))+geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

The sample plot is here:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/mZgTW]

Comment: Put the data into a long format (many answers for that on SO) and put only one thing in y.

Comment: you want position = "stack" too

Answer (score 3):

Your data is in the wrong format for a stack barchart, use the `melt` function from the `reshape` package to changes its format into something usable.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

df <- data.frame(Type = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h","i"),
             Value1 = c(1, 32, 63, 94, 125, 156,187,218,249),
             Value2 = c(125, 5, 125, 76, 3, 125,3,2,100),
             Total = c(126,37,188,170,128,281,190,220,349))

df.m <- melt(df,id.vars = "Type")

plot <- ggplot(df.m, aes(x = Type, y = value,fill=variable)) +
        geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

This should produce the below chart:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes your data needs to be reorganized. This is how you might do it manually. There are probably dozens of different was to do this in R.

```
Type = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f","g","h","i")
Value1 = c(1, 32, 63, 94, 125, 156,187,218,249)
Value2 = c(125, 5, 125, 76, 3, 125,3,2,100)
Total = c(126,37,188,170,128,281,190,220,349)
Type<-rep(Type,3)
Values<-c(Value1,Value2,Total)
Groups<-c(rep("Value1",9),rep("Value2",9),rep("Total",9))

df<-data.frame(Type,Values,Groups

ggplot(df, aes(x=Type,y=Values, fill=Groups)) + geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off with a line plot here:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

theme_set(theme_bw())

f.m = melt(f, id.var="Type")
f.m$variable = factor(f.m$variable, levels=c("Total", "Value1", "Value2"))

ggplot(f.m, aes(x=Type, y=value, group=variable, colour=variable)) + 
  geom_line(aes(size=variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", hcl(c(15,195),100,65))) +
  scale_size_manual(values=c(1,0.5,0.5))
```

[image]

Stacking `Total` along with `Value1` and `Value2` is misleading, because `Total` is the sum of the other two. If you need to use a bar plot, then a stacked plot of `Value1` and `Value2` (with `Total` excluded) gives you the total as well.

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(f.m %>% filter(variable != "Total") %>% 
         mutate(variable = factor(variable, c("Value2", "Value1"))), 
       aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

And although I prefer the line plot, I suppose there might be circumstances where you'd want to do something like this:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_bar(data=f.m %>% filter(variable=="Total"),
           aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=variable), stat="identity", width=0.8) +
  geom_bar(data=f.m %>% filter(variable != "Total"),
           stat="identity", position="dodge", width=0.5, colour="black",
           aes(x=Type, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("grey60", hcl(c(15,195),100,65)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With dplyr / tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(Variable, Value, -Type) %>% ggplot(aes(Type, Value, fill=Variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + scale_fill_manual(values = c('gray', 'skyblue', 'orange'))
```

[image]